# Custom model (not tf.estimator) with tf.feature_column.input_layer on different datasets at once?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running into an issue where I don't know how to define my network to run on two datasets at once with `tf.feature_column.input_layer`. In the "traditional" layout, I'd just use the `feed_dict` and manually pass in the training and testing data via some input-placeholder and output-placeholder but I thought it would be interesting to try and use the `input_layer`.

## Datasets

```
features, labels = dataset_iterator(training_files, config)
features_test, labels_test = dataset_iterator(testing_files, config)
```

## Network

```
dense_tensor = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features=features, feature_columns=columns)
for units in [256, 16]:
    dense_tensor = tf.layers.dense(dense_tensor, units, tf.nn.relu)
logits = tf.layers.dense(dense_tensor, 8)

# Verification
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.cast(logits, tf.int32), labels)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Training 
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=labels))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
```

Is there a way for me to use the `features_test` and `labels_test`?

My training process looks like the following:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    keep_iterating = True

    i = 0
    print('Accuracy: {}'.format(sess.run(accuracy)))
    while keep_iterating:
        i += 1
        try:
            _, loss_val, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, loss_op, accuracy])
            if i % 1000 == 1:
                print('Iteration: {}: Loss: {} Accuracy: {}'.format(i, loss_val, accuracy_val))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Iteration: {}: Loss: {} Accuracy: {}'.format(i, loss_val, accuracy_val))
            keep_iterating = False
        except Exception as e:
            keep_iterating = False
```

---

To clarify: I'm asking if it's possible to feed in separate things into

```
dense_tensor = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features=features, feature_columns=columns)
```

such that I can call `train_op` and have it run using the training iterator (features,labels) and call `accuracy` and have it run the testing iterator (features_test, labels_test).

Currently, calling `accuracy` still uses "features" from the training iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to do the following:

1) Wrap into

```
def train_func():
    return dataset_config(filenames=filename_list, batch_size=64, mapper=feature_proto.unpack, num_cpus=num_cpus)

def test_func():
    return dataset_config(filenames=evaluation_list, batch_size=4096, mapper=feature_proto.unpack, num_cpus=num_cpus)
```

2) Use

```
is_training = tf.placeholder_with_default(True, shape=(), name='Is_Training')
features, labels = tf.cond(is_training, train_func, test_func)
```

3) Modify the network inputs to

```
dense_tensor = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features=features, feature_columns=columns)
```

4) Modify `correct_pred` into

```
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.cast(logits, tf.int32), labels)
```

such that it now uses whatever labels were given